# Find the selected tab

Tags: jquery

I see in previous posts that someone has suggested the following to find the selected tab.

```
var numberOfSelectedTab = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active")
```

However, when I do this, I get an error in the console indicating that the tab is not initialized. How can I initialize the tab? (Note: I only call this after $(document).ready, so I don't know why it's not initialized. Any ideas either on how to initialize, or how to use another way to get the current selected tab? (I also saw recommendations to use "ui,newTab.index()" but what if no tab has been selected yet by the user?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
var numberOfSelectedTab = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected');
```

Also, hope you are calling this after you've initialized the tabs! :)

In case you want to perform something on selection/change of tab, then use below code:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var selectedIndex = ui.index;
        if (selectedIndex === 0) { 
            // first tab
        } else if(selectedIndex === 1) { 
            //second tab
        }
        //you can use switch as well, if you have many tabs
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful comments. How do I initialize the tabs? Are they initialized once $(document).ready occurs, or only after that? Do I need to programatically initialize them? If not, how to detect initialization?

Comment: `$("#tabs").tabs()` will initialize the tabs, and yes, you've to do that in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to twitter bootstrap tabs. Each twitter bootstrap tab needs to be activated individually ([check here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)). Make sure you are 'initializing' the tab using `$('#yourTab').tab('show');` before doing anything with the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a 3rd party extension or JqueryUI? Do you load tabs with a default selection?

Try adding a `.selected` class when the user clicks on a tab and remove that class from all other tabs.  That way you can call the `.selected` class to know which one was selected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your tab with

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  active: 1
})
```

You can also use

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "refresh" );
```

This will refresh and re-initialize the tabs, then you'll not get tab is not initialized error.

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh